# One-line solution for Pandas dataframe search

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I was wondering if there is a one-line (or two!) solution instead of using multiple for-loops for the following problem:

I want to calculate the difference between any `$weight` value if they are for the same `$ID`, `$orient`, and `$direct`:

```
$ID $spec   $view   $orient $direct $weight
9247    1   post    stance      0       2038.66 
9247    2   post    stance      15b     2177.74 
9247    4   post    stance      15f     1559.62 
9247    5   ant     stance      15b     2271.89     
9247    6   ant     stance      0       2075.44     
9247    7   ant     stance      15f     1438.31     
9247    8   post    fall        15a     1665.60     
9247    9   post    fall        15p     1742.82     
9119    1   ant     fall        0       994.48      
9119    2   ant     fall        15b     1081.44     
9119    3   post    fall        15b     1024.18 
9119    4   post    fall        0       1093.46 
9119    5   post    stance      15a     1220.13     
9119    6   post    stance      15p     1089.72     
9119    7   post    fall        15f     1056.21
```

For example, the difference between the first and fifth line should be calculated (2038.66 - 2075.44 = −36.78) and so on, and written in such a new dataframe:

```
$ID $orient $direct $weight-difference
9247    stance      0       −36.78  
9247    stance      15b     −94.15
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you want to create all the pairs with a one-liner?

Comment: something like : `df.assign(difference=df.groupby(['$ID','$orient','$direct'])['$weight'].diff().mul(-1)).dropna()` ?

Comment: I have been testing variations of the df.groupby(['$ID', '$orient', '$direct'], as_index=False)...

Comment: @anky_91, write your solution in answer part, it will be more helpful than a comment.

Comment: @nucsit026 Thanks :) just did , I was away from my system hence couldnt do it

Comment: @Silent, if anky's answer is accpeted to you, green mark would be a nice way to say thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with groupby:

```
df.assign(difference=df.groupby(['$ID','$orient','$direct'])['$weight'].diff().mul(-1))
                                                                      .dropna()
```

---

```
     $ID  $spec $view $orient $direct  $weight  difference
3   9247      5   ant  stance     15b  2271.89      -94.15
4   9247      6   ant  stance       0  2075.44      -36.78
5   9247      7   ant  stance     15f  1438.31      121.31
10  9119      3  post    fall     15b  1024.18       57.26
11  9119      4  post    fall       0  1093.46      -98.98
```

Comment: May I also ask how the two values of each pair can be written in separate columns (instead of calculating their difference)? One column the values with $view==ant and the other the $view==post

Comment: @Silent That would require a pivot but thats out of scope for the currebnt question: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) for different methods of pivot (for your usecase i think Q10)